# Team Foundation Server connection settings

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

Very inexperienced Visual Studio 2015 user here.

So, I went through the process of connecting to our Team Foundation Server.  I don't recall how I did it at all, but I'm connected.

A co-worker asked me for the settings for our TFS.  He just had a computer refresh and needs to set up his VS app again.

How do I find these settings?  Where can you see your Team Foundation Server settings that you used to connect to it?

Answer (score 1):

Explore the content of `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache`: there should be a `ServerMap.xml` file listing the connections to TFS/VSTS. Drop the `Services/v1.0/Registration.asmx` portion of the URL.

**Note**: `7.0` is for Visual Studio 2017,

Comment: Thanks, this helped me :-) For VS2015 the path is `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache`

Answer (score 0):

From the Connect page, choose the Connect to Team Project link to select a different account, TFS, or team project to connect to.

Connect to team projects:

[image]

Select the team projects that you will work on:

[image]

Connect to Team Foundation Server dialog box:

[image]

Microsoft has documentation on connecting to TFS from Visual Studio 2015, which is where these steps were taken from:

[Connect to Team Projects: Connect from Visual Studio or Team Explorer](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/connect/connect-team-projects#to-open-the-web-portal-from-team-explorer)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my problem is, is there a way to see all these settings for a connection once you're already connected?

Comment: It looks like you aren't able to actually _edit_ an existing connection to see the settings you used. What I would do is look at the URL of the existing connection and try replicate it in the `Add TFS` window's Preview section (as seen in image 3). The name of your server is already displayed in the TF Server List, so you'll just need to look at the path and port of your existing connection.